# Upload OVA with multiple vmdk's to OpenStack via Glance

Tags: openstack

I am trying to upload a OVA file to Openstack.

The ova file contains 5 files:

volume1.vmdk volume2.vmdk volume3.vmdk server.mf server.ovf

I uploaded the files with the following command:

```
glance image-create --name server --disk-format vmdk --container-format ovf --is-public False --file /path/to/file.ova --progress
```

However when I try to create a server off of the uploaded image, I get an error (viewable via the console) stating that there are no bootable volumes.

Comment: can you provide the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error from Glance. The image appears to upload fine, and sits as 1.3gb on disk (which is correct), however when the server boots, console shows no bootable volume.

Answer (score 1):

On the controller node, check your image status and formats.

a. Get your image id

# glance image list

b. Check the status on the image

- glance show IMAGE_ID
  glance image-show IMAGE_ID

c. When you upload the image, check the api logs.

#> tail -f /var/log/glance/api.log

c. Check the logs, when you fire up the instance

#> tail -f  /var/log/nova/scheduler.log

Should give you some details on what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the disk adapter type ( IDE versus SCSI ).
Try adding:

```
--property vmware_adaptertype="pvscsi" 
--property vmware_disktype="sparse" 
--property hypervisor_type="vmware" 
--property vmware_ostype="ubuntu64Guest"
```

( Google for more available options )